# Role Based Access in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)

@RestController
public class RbacAccess {

@GetMapping("/api/user")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public String userAccess() {
    return ">>> User Contents!";
}

@GetMapping("/api/admin")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public String adminAccess() {
    return ">>> Admin Contents";
}

}
```

I want to secure my method like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") 
public String userAccess() { 
    return ">>> User Contents!";
}
```

Here I want dynamic `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole(DynamicRome )")` after user logged in whether role is ADMIN or User. I do not want to hard coded it.

my tables are :

- user: id,user_name,email,password
- role: id ,role_name
- user_role: id,user_id,role_id
- group: group_id,group_name
- role_group: id,role_id,group_id

I want to secure my method like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") 
public String userAccess() { 
    return ">>> User Contents!"; 
}
```

Here I want dynamic `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole(DynamicRome )")` after user logged in whether role is ADMIN or User. I do not want to hard coded it. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question in order to understand what you really need from us.

Comment: @Md.SamiulArafin Add that in your question, not as a comment.